# Update bootstrap 3 progress bar with php and mysqli (NOT PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

I have completed my first Bootstrap/php/mysqli site and update the records on the site via my database when I add a customer account.  However, I have three progress bars that I would like to also change the number value of, by simply passing a value through the database table via php into the progress bar when need be.  Can I accomplish this without Ajax or jquery?
I know it's simple but when I connect the database and table with the values and pass a value through a progress bar the progress bar remains empty.  I used INT for the value in the MySQL table and inserted the php statement within the aria-value section but nothing is happening. Any advice appreciated.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you please provide some of your code so that others can more easily help you with your question?

Comment: If you want a live-action progress bar, then you are going to need ajax calls to your server in order to update the value, otherwise they will receive a static progress bar at whatever percentage was finished then the PHP output started.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dynamic progress bar or animated progress bar then you can use ajax/jquery, else if you want only to display a progress bar you need to print a simple a value in bootstrap code using PHP and My SQL heres what you can do...

**PHP Calculations Sample**

```
<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_progress WHERE id = '1' 
$conn = mysqli_connect('host','user','pass','database');
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$progress = $row['progress'];
?>
```

**Sample Code for the Bootstrap**

```
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <?php echo $progress; ?>%;"><?php echo $progress; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Considering that your table has a progress field which has value to be put in progress as %.

You can use it by fetching first row, or put a loop to fetch all records

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks all for responding.  I realized I was passing the wrong variable in the progress bar.  The code was a standard connection followed by a simple while loop and the variable $row was declared and I passed just the dollar sign.  But it is encouraging nonetheless to see your responses,
Thanks.
-Les